# Unstyled DIV with VIDEO child has higher height than it should

Tags: firefox, video, html, webkit, height

For some reason a basic unstyled DIV element has extra height tacked onto the bottom when it contains a VIDEO element (and possibly other elements - I haven't tested with many types).

```
<div><video src="my_movie.ogv"></video></div>
```

I have the above line of code in a barebones base HTML file. With Firefox or Safari/Chrome's (if I use an .mp4 file instead of course) DOM inspectors on I see that the computed height of the DIV element is anywhere from 2-5 pixels more than the height of the VIDEO element.

This doesn't seem like expected and intentional behavior. If I put a P element in there instead of a VIDEO element, for example, the DIV doesn't have any of the extra height.

Does anyone know why the browsers are rendering this configuration of DOM elements in this way?

Comment: Have you tried adding video { margin: 0; padding: 0; } to your css? It might be that FireFox is adding a standard padding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your markup is as above and there are no special styles applied to it, then the behavior you see is required by the CSS box model; the space is the size of the font's descent, because the bottom of the video is placed by default on the baseline, not at the bottom of the text.  In particular, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22274#c55 for an explanation in spec terms and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22274#c37 for how to get rid of the space if you want to.  You could also set line-height on the block to 0 to get rid of the space; which approach you take should depend on your other design constraints.

Comment: Certainly interesting reading! Thanks for the links. I'm going to go through the second one now and see if it helps me with my issue. Thanks again, buddy!

Comment: For the time being I added styles to the containing block element to explicitly define width and height which works fine in Firefox but not in Safari where the containing block element has some space both above AND below the video element.

Comment: Never mind... after some examination of the media files themselves I realized that the ogv and mp4 versions of the same video are slightly different heights for some reason. I used Firefogg to encode the ogv file and got a file exactly 640x360 whereas with Handbrake I ended up with an mp4 that's 640x352 even though I told it to give me 640x360.